# Как выполнить определённый кусок кода через прокси в Python

Tags: python, proxy

Нужно выполнять некоторые строки кода через прокси, возможно это делается с помощь with, но я не понимаю как это реализовать. Напишу по колхозному, главное чтобы суть понятна была

```
with (подключение к прокси):
    действие
```

Comment: Что такое прокси?

Comment: Выбирайте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python+proxy